# How to assign roles based on group name when a user login in Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to assign roles to the user who successfully login to a Spring web app. I am using LDAP authentication to do this.

My **WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.logsniffer.web.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception
    {
        if ("h2".equals(env.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")))
            return;

        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://10.100.7.99:389/dc=ldap,dc=com");
        context.afterPropertiesSet();

        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(context)
                .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
                .userSearchBase("ou=support")
       //         .groupSearchBase("ou=support")
       //         .groupSearchFilter(String groupSearchFilter)
                .groupRoleAttribute("cn")
                .rolePrefix("");


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
 //               .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
         }
}
```

Maybe I am understanding this wrong. I thought using

```
.groupRoleAttribute("cn")
```

sets the user role. But when I try to print the user authorities like,

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String r= authentication.getAuthorities().toString();
log.info("$$$$$$$$$$ " + r);
```

I get an empty string. My LDAP tree has the following configuration

```
+--> dc=ldap,dc=com (1+)
---> cn=admin
---> ou=hr
+--> ou=support (1+)
| +--> cn=admin (2)
| | ---> cn=kaushan deva
| | ---> cn=sameera ramasinghe
| | ---> Create new entry here
| +--> cn=regular (1)
| | ---> cn=chamitha abe
```

I am prettry sure in `registerGlobalAuthentication` method, the way I'm trying to authenticate users is wrong. That is why I cannot set group role attributes. But I cannot find the error since I am very new to this.

What I want to do is to set user roles to each user who logs in, based on his group (`admin` or `regular`).

Comment: yes it is zero. Thanks for the link. I will go through it. Meanwhile, if you could provide some insight to this question, that would be great

Answer (score -1):

Second way you can do like this with ApplicationDetailService:

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encryptDecrypt);
    }
```

ApplicatonDetailService:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

       com.your.User domainUser = userDAO.findByEmail(username);

       List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
       return new User(domainUser.getEmail(), domainUser.getPassword(),
            enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked, authList);

    }
}
```

You can set the Role based on Condition:

```
 List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using login success handler in Spring. Below the example of the Code.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/app/url")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }
```

Login Success Handler:

```
@Component
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user =     (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        String name = user.getUsername(); 
        //Your Code based on code and set role in Spring Security 
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }
}
```